# React Native App has black border not edge-to-edge fullscreen in iPad 3rd Generation

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad-3

My React Native app shows edge-to-edge fullscreen on all iOS versions of iPad and iPhone (including iPhone X with its rounded corners) but on iPad 3rd Generation it shows with a black border around the outside of the app.

How do I make it fullscreen? e.g. I want my app to continue under the the top status bar and into the rounded corners.

e.g. Screenshot shows how the Native Map App works fullscreen but my app only fills the green area and has black borders around the edge.

[image]